# PHP advanced array combinations

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time trying to explain what I want here. So I'll just try to explain it with some code:

```
// Example 1

$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$in_each = 2;

$combinations = superFunction($numbers, $in_each);

// Result

$combinations = [
    [
        [1,2],
        [3,4],
        [5,6]
    ],
    [
        [1,3],
        [2,4],
        [5,6]
    ],
    [
        [1,4],
        [2,3],
        [5,6]
    ]
    // and so on
];


// Example 2

$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$in_each = 3;

$combinations = superFunction($numbers, $in_each);

// Result

$combinations = [
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6]
    ],
    [
        [1,2,4],
        [3,5,6]
    ]
    // and so on
];
```

It is the **superFunction** I need help with creating. Note the variable **$in_each** is key here.

The function doesn't need to be superefficient or even fail-safe. I just need something to get me started.

I've seen many different "array combo" scripts on here, but none with the option of "grouping them" like this.

Comment: Why not use one of those existing combo scripts, then walk through the resultant array using [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Do you want to have all available combinations or just keep the first/secon number at first place?

Comment: I can't understand how your combinations are split into arrays. Obvious, they are `C(n,k)` for each `k` - but how are they split in first level of result array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I didn't know about this before, but [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/array_chunk) would do what you want without the effort of making a function. Didn't realize it existed. It seems as easy as `array_chunk($numbers, $in_each);`

The [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) function can probably help out for doing what you want. I'm pretty sure you just want to split the `$numbers` array into equal parts determined by the `$in_each` variable.

Here's a quick example:

```
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
$in_each = 2;
$combinations = array_slice($nums, 0, 0 + $in_each);
```

If you printed out `$combinations` at this point, this is what you would get:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
)
```

So, I would just setup `superFunction` as a loop that does array_slice `n` times where `n` is the `length of $numbers` divided by `$in_each`. `n` would also go up from zero by however big your `$in_each` variable is. In this case, `n` would count like this: `0 2 4`.